# 1 iOS Distribution certificate for 3 different applications

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, certificate, provisioning-profile

Can I use the same distribution Certificate with multiple applications (limit 3)? I ask this because I am not able to create more than 3 Distribution / Production certificates in the Portal. I need one certificate for a new app that I am working on and was wondering if I can use one of the existing certificates and create a new Provisioning Profile for my app.

Thanks,
Sahitya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the same iOS Distribution certificate for multiple applications. Note of the following requirements:

- Each application must have it's own App ID.
- Each application needs new Distribution provisioning profile
- Certificate must be valid and not expired.

Comment: You mean there is no limit on the number of applications that use the distribution certificate in question?

Comment: There should be no limit, we are currently using the same certificate for 3 apps.

Comment: :) 3 apps only? I assume you havent tried for more apps. Do let me know whar happens when you use it for more. Thanks till then ;)

Comment: I see no reason why it would not work for more (I just work with multiple developer teams and they have 1-3 apps usually).

Comment: @Legoless is it possible to use different Distribution certificates per app? ( And publish them to App Store, of course )